# Corollary from lemma in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

We know that there is very useful lemma in number theory.

**Lemma:** If $a$ is relatively prime to $b$ but $a\mid bc$, then $a\mid c$.

Following immediately from the lemma and the definition of prime number is the important

*Corollary* If a prime number divides the product of certain integers it must divide at least one of these integers.

This corollary is obvious to me and I proved it via cintradiction.
However, I was not able to derive immediately using above lemma and definition of prime number.

Can anyone help with that, please?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p|ab$. If $p|a$, it is done. Otherwise $(p,a)=1$ and by the lemma, $p|b$.